# while one website host is down, can I set up another host to take over, untill the first host goes back up

Tags: website, hosts, ubuntu-server, lamp

Basically I have a simple free host ([000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com)) that I used to use. Now I have my own machine to host a website. however, when I'm updating stuff on that machine, or anything that might make the computer to go down temporarily, I would like the other host to be able to host the site until the first one is back up.

On my new hosting computer I'm using Ubuntu server, using lamp stack (apache, mysql, php), and am using wordpress.

Comment: I'd recommend trying out AWS free tier: http://aws.amazon.com/free/ You can get some proper load balancing and failover out of it too if you're willing to pay a few pennies now and then.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is a Network Load Balance setup, in that both machines use a shared virtual IP in a round robin arrangement.  When one goes down, the NLB stops routing calls to that box, and the other box gets all the requests until the first box comes back up.

The problem with NLB is, it doesn't enforce sync between the two servers, it's just a traffic cop. So you'd need some other arrangement to ensure that your content is synced between the two systems. NLB typically is used across two or more (we use groups of five) web servers that are for all intents and purposes identically configured.

The arrangement that you're using (hosting locally AND on a leased remote system) is a bit backward, IMO.  I would recommend that you push all your "production" content to the web host, and use your local system for development and testing only.

Comment: when I say hosting locally, I ment I got a new computer meant for dedecating hosting, not a local working enviorment. I also have a 3rd local host for developing on (my laptop).

it might be a good thing that the two don't host identically. I might want to disable commenting and stuff on the onlnie host, so I don't have to worry about putting the comments in the first server when it goes back online

Comment: The problem that you're facing here is that your hosting spans two networks, so that you must resort to a DNS redirect to switch the 'active' web host from one to the other.  This is a time-consuming fix, which requires both hosts to be up (and sync'd) during the DNS TTL period, while the transition is taking place.   An NLB solution typically has all hosts in the same subnet, so that they can be coordinated properly.  Or, one could simply switch the IP's (which is what I do with my shoutcast servers, they're identical VM's with access to a shared external drive).

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the question I think it is clear the OP clearly wants this to switch on / off when a server is down (when up, take traffic, when down, point else where) with instant results.

This can't be done.

If the computer is down, then so is everything that is being hosted. If the computer is down, then you can't run any forwarding scripts from that machine, meaning the only way is if on the registrar's site (where domain name is registered) you could try and get a server response and on error, forward to a different IP.

Updating DNS records I don't think will work, simpily because typically it takes up to 72 hours to propagate and OP says it's only during the machine going down 'temporarily'.

Comment: This can be done. It's just not a good way to do it.

Comment: @r.tanner.f Please explain how then

Comment: Change the DNS records to point to another host.

Comment: @r.tanner.f Changing DNS records takes up to 72 hours! how does this answer the question then OP states 'temporarily down'? I don't see how this is even a consideration

Comment: As I said, it's _possible_, but it's bad. Your answer makes it sound __impossible__.

Comment: @r.tanner.f Please explain then how a DNS could be changed for the moment of shut down, and then returns for when the server is back up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7059/discussion-between-r-tanner-f-and-dave-rook)

Comment: It's possible to decrease the [DNS TTL duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records), depending on your nameserver. The one I currently use will allow me to decrease it to 60 seconds. The only issue is if a caching server caches it for longer than the TTL specifies, but there isn't really anything that can be done with such nonstandard behaviour.

Comment: It might be possible by pointing all web traffic to a third host, and letting that forward it to either the webhost or the backup webhost. Inefficient though. A proper " dev - test - production" setup would be much better.

Comment: @Hennes, I think good point (but as you subtly hinted, (and for clarity to other readers) if this goes down, then no website shows at all which totally defeats the point of the question (at least, as to how I understand it) :)  )

Comment: Aye. It only helps if the font server is stable (no reason why it should not be) and the webmaster makes a mistake while updating the website, thus taking the main webserver down due to human error. -- Making an error while updating the front/forwarder server would still cause failure.

Comment: @DaveRook IP addresses changes propagate within an hour in most cases. I am actually setting up my new hosting servers and I constantly change the server IP's. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/532532/3981) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution in just to change the DNS to make it points to the new website

Comment: Doesnt that have a propagation time of around 48 hours?

Comment: That was years ago. Currently DNS changes propagates in just a few minutes or even less.

Comment: @jap1968: That depends on the TTL... My host's DNS, for example, has it set to 24 hours, and I cannot change it.  Thus, my changes do not propagate "in just a few minutes."

Answer (score 0):

There's a technology call Web Server Clustering, just like Google, facebook, microsoft, i'm sure they have a lot of identical server serving the entire internet request. one single server from those is not able to meet the demand of the entire web community.

Facebook.com for example has mutiple ipaddress (A record) that points to different IP Address.

But I'm not sure how it's setup.